# The different between <item name="title"> and <item name="android:title">

Tags: android

I make ActionBar in app.I change ActionBar style.There are some questions.
I want to change the title in the ActionBar.
So I write the follow code.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflowButton</item>
    </style>
    <!--ActionBar-->
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/bg</item>
        <item name="background">@color/bg</item>
        <item name="android:title">@string/test</item>
        <item name="title">@string/test</item>
    </style>
    <style name="overflowButton">
        <item name="android:src">@mipmap/ic_add_black_48dp</item>
        <item name="android:showAsAction"></item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

when I only write `<item name="android:title">@string/test</item>` ,it doesn't work,but write `<item name="title">@string/test</item>` it work.
I have try to solve in Android Developer,but fail.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="title">@string/test</item>
```

this tag works on supporting library, and

```
<item name="android:title">@string/test</item>
```

this one works on your android. For more detail please have a look on [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

I hope you understand, If not please let me know.

Comment: my android is 4.0,my supporting library is 5.0.As you say,I write <item name="android:title">@string/test</item> will work in my android,but it doesn't.

Comment: You are using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, This is support library's theme only. So here `<item name="title">@string/test</item>` only works.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar, then you must use (or override) the Theme.AppCompat family of styles (rather than the Theme.Holo family, available in API level 11 and higher). In doing so, each style property that you declare must be declared twice: once using the platform's style properties (the android: properties) and once using the style properties included in the Support Library (the appcompat.R.attr properties—the context for these properties is actually your app).